# Mongodb - Created Index - Is it required and am i searching ok?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

2 parts to my post here:

1) A confirmation:
I've created an index using: the standard:

`db.collection.createIndex( { order: 1, code: 1 } )`

So from here can someone confirm this is the best thing to do (creating the index) if i then want to run a query such as. (Also if i dont create index whats the difference it technically makes, is it just on impacting performance)

```
db.collection.find( {order : {$in: ['food', 'drink']}} )
```

2) Syntax
With the query I want to use a `or` however its showing an error, could someone kindly check is my syntax correct here:

```
db.collection.find( $or[{order : {$in: ['food', 'drink']}}, {code : {$in: ['12', '14']}}]  )
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `$or` operator form is as following

```
{ $or: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> }, ... , { <expressionN> } ] }
```

So

```
db.collection.find( {$or: [{order : {$in: ['food', 'drink']}}, 
                           {code : {$in: ['12', '14']}}]}  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Since zangw has answered question 2, I just answer question 1.

`db.collection.createIndex( { order: 1, code: 1 } )` will create index named
`order_1_code_1`, which can speed up your both queries. If the fields in query can form prefix of index name, MongoDB can use index. So if your only query by `code`, the index `order_1_code_1` is useless.